# Display a video in a VideoView from Firebase URL in Android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-videoview

When I run my app I'm having these issues.

- A black screen flashes for 2 secs and then displays the actual intent of my app.
- The video gets **started** and when I scroll up/down, the `VideoView` turns white and continues playing. Not able to see the video but plays in background.
- After playing is done, for few seconds I'm getting this "Can't play this video" dialog.

This is the excerpt from my **Adapter** Code:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message> {
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView authorTextView, timeStamp, messageTitle, messageTextView;
        VideoView videoView;
        ImageView photoImageView;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Gets the message that we are displaying at a position
        Message message = getItem(position);

        ...

        boolean isPhoto = message.getPhotoUrl() != null;
        boolean isVideo = message.getVideoUrl() != null;

        if (isPhoto) {
            // Photo Present

        } else if (isVideo) {
            // Video present
            Log.d(TAG, "Video present !");
            viewHolder.messageTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.photoImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.timeStamp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.videoView.setVideoPath(message.getVideoUrl());
            viewHolder.videoView.start();
            Log.d(TAG, "Video URL : "+message.getVideoUrl());
        } else {
            // Photo and video both absent
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I'm getting this on `LogCat`:

After displaying the Logged info there is a following warning as shown below

```
D: Video present !
D: Video URL : https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxx.appspot.com/o/photos%2Fvideo%3A34334?alt=media&token=05xf6c2f-6abc-4ab9-b696-32153fa3d0aa
W: Couldn't open https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxx.appspot.com/o/photos%2Fvideo%3A34334?alt=media&token=05cf6c2f-6abc-4ab9-b696-32153fa3d0aa: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxx.appspot.com/o/photos%2Fvideo%3A34334?alt=media&token=05cx6c2f-6abc-4ab9-b696-32153fa3d0aa
I: proxyName: 0.0.0.0 0
W: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
D: getMetadata
I: proxyName: 0.0.0.0 0
W: info/warning (703, 0)
I: proxyName: 0.0.0.0 0
V: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
I: proxyName: 0.0.0.0 0
I: proxyName: 0.0.0.0 0
E: error (1, -2147483648)
```

This is my `VideoView` Layout:

```
<VideoView 
    android:id = "@+id/admin_video_view"
    android:layout_width = "300dp"
    android:layout_height = "200dp"
    android:layout_weight = "1"
    android:layout_marginLeft = "10dp"
    android:paddingTop = "5dp"
    android:scaleType = "centerCrop" />
```

Comment: Where is a Firebase? Have you started this app in other devices or emulators?

Comment: @CoolMind That's in my MainActivity. Updated my question with that just now. Please see above.

Comment: Now that I've downloaded locally from Firebase Storage to my Mobile Storage. Got a hint from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42057701/7004388). Now the question is, where do i set the path of the Video in `MessageAdapter` ? or `MainActivity` ? Can you please guide me. @CoolMind

Comment: Is it working good if you try from a local resource like a `.mp4` movie stored in `raw` folder?

Comment: @PC. could you avoid writing comments to answers to unrelated questions with the sole purpose of linking to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **culprit** here is `android.widget.VideoView` which extends `SurfaceView`.

[This blog](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/embedding-videoviews-in-your-ui-caution) says:

> Playing a video using a `VideoView` inside of a row of a `ListView` seems to work at first, until the user tries to scroll the list. As
>   soon as the list starts to scroll, the video turns black (sometimes displays white). It keeps
>   playing in the background but you can’t see it anymore because it
>   renders the rest of the video as a black box.

I wrote my own `VideoView` class which extends `TextureView` with the help of this [github](https://github.com/aizhang/Android-VideoView/blob/master/src/com/ai/videoview/widget/VideoView.java) repository. Though It has some issues as it was written 3 years ago I managed to fix them on my own. Very soon I'll update this answer with my custom **Optimized VideoView** github repository (just with few modifications). Until then, the link which I've provided would help you.

With the custom **Optimized VideoView**, the videos will play on scroll in the `ListView` just like our Instagram, Facebook, Twitter. We can make the videos play/pause  by setting `setOnTouchListener()` on `VideoView` in our activity and can customize it in our own way.

Now, our `VideoView` in the Layouts would be:

```
<your.packagename.VideoView
    android:id="@+id/admin_video_view"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp" />
```

Comment: I would be curious to know if it worked with `RecyclerView` (without the aid of an external library), but I'm glad you got `ListView` working.

Comment: Don't forget to link to your new optimized repository when it is ready.